# About derived set, boundary set and the domain of a function

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

I need to understand if my reasoning about this exercise is correct.

> Be $A$ the natural domain of the function $$f(x_1, x_2) = \ln\left(\frac{2x_1}{x_2}\right)$$
> then the point $P = (0, 2) \in ...$

> $\Box$ $A \cap D(A)$

> $\Box$ $D(A)\backslash \partial(A)$

> $\Box$ $\partial(A)\backslash D(A)$

> $\Box$ $D(A)\cap \partial(A)$

Where $D$ is the derived set and $\partial$ is the boundary set.

I believe the correct answer must be the last one. The natural domain $A$ of the function is given by $$(x_1, x_2) \in\mathbb{R}^2 - \{0, 0\}$$

This is meant as "both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive or they are both negative".

This means that the derived set and the boundary should be

$$D(A) = \mathbb{R}^2$$
$$\partial(A) = \{0\}$$

am I right? I still have some confusion about those...
Anyway since $x_1 = 0$ the middle answers have to be trashed.
The first one too, and the last one is the only one in which $0$ is allowed.

However, $x_2 = 2$ would not be inside their intersection... What am I missing?

Comment: I am not getting the same set for the domain of $f$

Comment: Uhm, I wrote it in a bad way, but basically it's when both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive or both negative, right?

Comment: yes, your words are right. One way to write that: $A=\{(x,y): xy > 0\}$, ```$A=\{(x,y): xy > 0\}$```